# Node.js and PHP on port 80 on same server

Tags: php, webserver, node.js

I have a node.js site running on port 8080 of my Linux server. I also have, on the same sarver, a PHP site (bugzilla) running on port 80. So my current configuration is:

- http://example.com:8080 (node.js application)
- http://example.com/bugzilla (bugzilla site)

I want to have both sites running on port 80 like this:

- http://example.com/mynodejs (node.js application)
- http://example.com/bugzilla (bugzilla site)

Is that possible?

Comment: You can't have both applications listening on the same port. But I think what you're probably looking for is a 'reverse proxy'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, disable both services on your machine. then change their ports into something unusual and restart them, for example:

- PHP application on `6821`
- NodeJS application on `6822`

Please remember to open them on `127.0.0.1` ! you shouldn't open them on your network interface.

---

Install `nginx` as the most used `Reverse Proxy`. Depends on your distribution you can install it with one of these commands:

**For Debian based distributions:**

```bsh
$ sudo apt install nginx
```

**For Arch based distributions:**

```bsh
$ sudo pacman -S nginx
```

Completely depends on your distro again, this package could have its own files hierarchical. so I will give you just `nginx.conf` as the main config file. **Just remember to copy original config file with any name you prefer, something like** `nginx.conf.origin`

```bsh
$ sudo cp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.origin
```

Now, open `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, remove existing configs and copy these configurations inside it:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    keepalive_timeout  15;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  example.com; 

        location /mynodejs {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6822;
        }

        location /bugzilla {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6821;
        }
    }
}
```

**Notice: Please consider that I wrote this config file with my mind, and because of that you probably will face with an error when you want to run nginx. If so, please write a comment here, so I will test it.**

Now, Just restart your nginx! You will get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The php app can stay where it is unmodified.

When using apache as the webserver, the proxy modules need to be enabled.  On ubuntu for example

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

And modify your virtualhost with the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` lines.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/www.example.com/htdocs"
        #nodejs app
        ProxyPass /mynodejs http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse /mynodejs http://127.0.0.1:8080/
<Directory "/var/www/www.example.com/htdocs"> 
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All 
        Order allow,deny 
        Allow from all 
</Directory>
        ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /var/www/www.example.com/logs/%Y-%m-%d/error_log" 
        CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /var/www/www.example.com/logs/%Y-%m-%d/access_log" combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart apache `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.